# How to retrive text from a div tag

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my SeleniumWebdriver test, I need to retrieve the text of a fieldlabel-content based on the fieldlabel-label to ensure info provided for every fieldlable-label is correct.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="gridlayout-row" style="padding-top: 0px;">
<div class="gridlayout-column" style="padding-left: 0px; width: calc((100% - 110px) * 0.166667 + 10px);">
    <div class="gridlayout-content">
        <label class="fieldlabel">
            <div class="fieldlabel-label">Type</div>
            <div class="fieldlabel-content">Paid</div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="gridlayout-column" style="padding-left: 10px; width: calc((100% - 110px) * 0.166667 + 10px);">
    <div class="gridlayout-content">
        <label class="fieldlabel">
            <div class="fieldlabel-label">Expires</div>
            <div class="fieldlabel-content">Jul 27, 2017</div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="gridlayout-column" style="padding-left: 10px; width: calc((100% - 110px) * 0.166667 + 10px);">
    <div class="gridlayout-content">
        <label class="fieldlabel">
            <div class="fieldlabel-label">Last update</div>
            <div class="fieldlabel-content">Jul 12, 2017</div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find div element with class fieldlabel-label using its text and use following-sibling to get element with fieldlabel-content class.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fieldlabel-content and contains(text(), 'Expires')']/following-sibling::div[@class='fieldlabel-content']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Xpath :- `//div[text()="Type"]/following-sibling::div[@class="fieldlabel-content"]`

In above xpath you can provide dynamic 'fieldlable-label' text in first div. On the biases of that you can get respective fieldlabel-content value.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()="Type"]/following-sibling::div[@class="fieldlabel-content"]")).getText();
```