# Using Selenium Webdriver how to retrive date text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With selenium webdriver I need to get the text from a div tag which has a date in it how to go with that

here is the HTML tag showing the div tag.

```
<div class="gridlayout-column" style="padding-left: 10px; width: calc((100% - 110px) * 0.166667 + 10px);">
    <div class="gridlayout-content">
        <label class="fieldlabel">
            <div class="fieldlabel-label">Last update</div>
            <div class="fieldlabel-content">Jul 12, 2017</div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I stored created a webelement for the above and tried using

```
WebElement lastUpdate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[ . = 'Last update' and //div[contains(@class, 'fieldlabel-content')]]/following-sibling::div[@class='fieldlabel-content']"));

lastUpadte.getText();
```

The output was --

So I another option which is this

```
Date expiryDate = null;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM DD, YYYY");
    String dateString = lastUpdate.getText();
     try {
       expiryDate = formatter.parse(dateString);
    } 
     catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Still it didn't work. I am sure I am not doing it properly so please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrive text from a div tag which where 3 webelement has the same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155690/how-to-retrive-text-from-a-div-tag-which-where-3-webelement-has-the-same-class-n)

Comment: Is the getText for this xpath "//label[@class='fieldlabel']/div[2]" returning the date?

Comment: Can you add your selenium code in your question? We need to see where does the `webElement` come from.

Comment: `WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[ . = 'Last update' and //div[contains(@class, 'fieldlabel-content')]]/following-sibling::div[@class='fieldlabel-content']"));

        webElement.getText();` remove findElementdriver from you code. And try again.

Comment: @Buaban I have added the webElement part

Comment: @SudhaVelan sorry that was a typo in my question I have updated it

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?getting the date is some other format?

Comment: Getting date in DD/MMM/YYY format as I got to use that to compare with UTC time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code to get the `date`

```
String date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gridlayout-content']//div[@class='fieldlabel-content']")).getText();
System.out.println(date);
```

> OR

you can do this way.

```
WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gridlayout-content']//div[@class='fieldlabel-content']"));
String s = date.getText();
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your XPath is incorrect. You have a couple choices to fix the XPath expression.

First: Find the date element based on sibling text value 'Last update'.

```
WebElement lastUpdate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[div='Last update']/*[@class='fieldlabel-content']");
```

Second: Find the date element by go into the sibling by text 'Last update' and then up to the parent and find the date.

```
WebElement lastUpdate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Last update']/../*[@class='fieldlabel-content']");
```

You can get the date text by:

```
lastUpdate.getAttribute("innerText");
```

Finally, you need to change the [date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to `"MMM dd, yyyy"`.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

Comment: Hello @Buaban , I guess for retrieving date from html, you should use `String`, instead of using `Webelement`. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @JainishKapadia I've added code to get text. Thanks for your question.

Comment: Refer my answer, your answer will not return the date, it will return the `xpath` in console window.

Comment: @JainishKapadia I totally don't understand your point. My answer will fix the xpath so it can find the element. Then it can get text from the element.

Comment: You are code printing `webelement`, but question is printing date as `text`.